# How can i a surround multiple inputs from a form with a div tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, helper, simple-form

I am currently working on a rails app that has a common pattern on fields throughout many forms and many fields of the same form. This is the pattern:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@evaluation) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="toggle">

    <div class="toggle_selector">
      <%= f.input :was_answered, :as => :radio, :collection => [:yes, :no, '?'] %>
    </div>

    <div class="toggle_content">
      <%= f.input :name %>
      <%= f.input :answer %>
      <%= f.input :score %>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

There is a main div tag that surrounds two other divs. The toggle_content div is made visible or not, using javascript, based on the value from the input that is in toggle_selector div.

I tried to extract a couple helpers that would take the inputs as parametes and output the desired output:

```
def toggling_field_for form, selector, &block                            
  content_tag :div, :class => 'toggle' do                                
    %{#{toggle_selector form, selector}                                  
      #{toggle_content &block if block_given?}                           
    }.html_safe                                                          
  end                                                                    
end                                                                      

private                                                                  

def toggle_selector form, selector                                       
    content_tag :div, :class => 'toggle_selector' do                     
      form.input selector, :as => :radio, :collection => [:yes, :no, '?']
    end                                                                  
end                                                                      

def toggle_content                                                       
  content_tag :div, :class => 'toggle_content' do                        
    yield if block_given?                                                
  end                                                                    
end
```

However, this will only work if i only have one input on the toggle_content div, because when i use the yield on the block of inputs, only the last one will be output.

Anyone could give a hint on a better solution to refactor these to be able to accept more than one input on the toggle_content div?

Edited: Problem solved using the capture helper method instead of just yield. The code ended up like this on the helper:

```
def toggling_field_for form, selector, &block
  content_tag :div, :class => 'toggle' do
    %{#{toggle_selector form, selector}
      #{toggle_content &block}
    }.html_safe
  end
end

private

def toggle_content &block
  content_tag :div, capture(&block), :class => 'toggle_content'
end
```

And called like this on each form:

```
    <%= toggling_field_for f, :was_answered, do %>
        <%= f.input :name %>
        <%= f.input :answer %>
        <%= f.input :score %>
    <% end %>
```

Thanks, mosch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Rails 3, your code should work with a slight modification: Try changing

```
def toggle_content                                                       
  content_tag :div, :class => 'toggle_content' do                        
    yield if block_given?                                                
  end                                                                    
end
```

to

```
def toggle_content(&block)
  content_tag :div, :class => 'toggle_content' do                        
    capture(&block) if block_given?
  end                                                                    
end
```

I am not sure, but you can probably remove the block_given? clause in that case.

Comment: That capture helper method was exactly what i was looking for, it solved my problem, thanks! I just had to make some changes for it to work properly and the block_given? was no longer necessary.